# stored procedure returns data of varying dimensions Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

for the reporting of a survey system I am working on, we developed a stored procedure that  returns data with varying number of columns.

we show the operator all the columns from these tables: Users, Questions, Answers.

the user selects the columns from each of the tables that the report should show.
for example:
 User: Name, Age, zipcode.
Questions: question2, question 4 
Answers:  answer2, answer3, answer4.

we then pass the parameters to the stored procedure and the stored procedure returns:
one column for each user property, question or answer.
and a row for each user in the DB.

example:
    [image: example]

as you can see, the stored procedure can return anything between 3 rows of 2 columns to 500 rows of 50 columns.   Is there a way to use the stored procedure with entity framework? at first I tried with a complex return type, but it appears that that approach will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF supports only stored procedures with fixed number of columns defined at design time. To execute this procedure you need to use plain old ADO.NET.

EDIT: If you have fixed total nuber of colums (you mentioned 50) you can create single class containing all these columns and use it as result for execution. EF will fill only properties existing in the result set.